# Get path to dll - original path, not shadowed assembly

Tags: c#

As stated in the title, I am looking for the path of a dll, where the actual code lies. (in c#)

I have tried

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location
```

and

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.CodeBase
```

but both of these give me the path of the dll file in the solution of the app that's using the dll, aka

```
C:\Users\Edan\repos\TestProgram\TestProgram\bin\Debug\FileSave.dll
```

where I would like

```
C:\Users\Edan\repos\FileSave\FileSave\bin\Debug\FileSave.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

By default VS will copy all referenced Dll's into the build folder of the exe that is referencing the DLL.  This is because .net by default only searches the directory where the executable lives and its sub directories.  The referenced DLL "FileSave.dll" has no knowledge of its original build location.

Is there a reason you need the original location?

Comment: That makes sense. I have a SQLite database in there, because it is the dll which interfaces with it, so I figured putting it in there would be sensible. There are multiple points of entry from different apps to the db which needs to contain the same data. Is there a more ideal location for it in that case? Or can I force the app to also shadow the database and somehow keep the copies synchronized?

Comment: You can do either.  What I would suggest though is to have calling apps set the database location either explicitly or though configuration.  Utility DLL's having control of their own storage is hard for consumers to discover. 

If you want to copy the file you can use a build step to do that however if you want a shared file you should use mklink so that the copies point back to the same file.